# Using Point and BigInteger

Tags: java, pointers, biginteger

How can I use Point in Java with BigInteger? Below is an example of what I'm trying to do. The new Point generator throws an error that it cant convert BigInterger to Int which I can fix by doing .intValue() but then on the publicKey line it throws an error with using the .multiply().

```
    // Parts of one ECC system.
    private EllipticCurve curve;
    private Point generator;
    private Point publicKey;
    private BigInteger privateKey;
    
    // We need a curve, a generator point (x,y) and a private key, nA, that will
    // be used to generate the public key.
    public ECC(EllipticCurve c, BigInteger x, BigInteger y, BigInteger nA) {
            
            curve = c;
            generator = new Point(x, y);
            privateKey = nA;
            publicKey = generator.multiply(privateKey);
    }
```

Than later in the code I'm trying to use a Point[] and I'm having issues.

```
            public Point decrypt(Point[] cipher) {
            
            // This is what we subtract out.
            Point sub = cipher[0].multiply(privateKey);
            
            // Subtract out and return.
            System.out.println("sub of "+cipher[1]+" - "+sub);
            return cipher[1].subtract(sub);
    }
```

Comment: What does the `Point` class look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Point` cannot be declared with `BigInteger`, I don't know why you need to use `Point`. Instead, you can create your class `MyPoint` and declare a `BigInteger` member fields `x` and `y`.

```
class MyPoint {
    BigInteger x, y;
    
    myPoint(BigInteger x, BigInteger y){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y; 
    }

}
```

Comment: In Java 16 and later, use a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395): `record BigPoint ( BigInteger x, BigInteger y ) {}`